# Rocket League controller only works on Press Any Button to Start screen

Tags: pc, controllers, rocket-league

When I start Rocket League, I press a button on my controller at the screen that says "Press Any Button to Start".  That brings up the main menu, but my controller no longer works to control the menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when you have more than 1 game controller attached to your computer.  Rocket League picks one of the controllers to be the primary controller, and other controllers can only be used as Player 2.  Windows has a setting to select your default controller, but as far as I can tell Rocket League pays no attention to that setting.

But I have found a workaround for this bug.  When it happens:

1. Unplug all controllers and controller-like devices.  For wireless controllers, turn them off.  (In my case, I have a Razer Tartarus Pro gaming keypad, which also shows up as a game controller.)
2. Plug in or turn on your primary controller.  Rocket League should now allow you to control the menus with it.
3. Plug in your other devices.  Rocket League should continue to use your primary controller for Player 1.

You don't need to exit Rocket League before performing this procedure.

Once I've gone through this procedure, I can generally play Rocket League multiple times without having to do it again.  I may or may not need to repeat it after rebooting.

Comment: On some platforms, there's a "reorder controllers" feature that can be used to achieve the same thing without having to physically reconnect anything.